# POST with API in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to POST data via an API but i'm getting an error 420 'Enhance your calm'.

If there is something i'm doing wrong ? (if you have another method in C# to POST in an API always welcome to share your solution )

Thank you

```
        try {
            HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient();
            client2.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://kbhb-officialpayments-test.sportlink-interfaces.net/entity/kbhb/officialpayments/UnionOfficialOfficialAssignment");
            client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer aaafdsqgfdsgfdsgfzq");
            client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "");
            request.Content = new StringContent("{\"PersonId\":\""+ personID + "\",\"FunctionId\":\"" + functionID + "\",\"ExternalMatchId\":\"" + matchID + "\",\"DistrictId\":\"" + district + "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header

            client2.SendAsync(request)
                  .ContinueWith(responseTask => {
                      Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result);
                  });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: `Enhance your calm` is pretty much telling you what to do, slow down your requests and dont fire to much in a short period of time.

Comment: Btw, you should give the documentation a read - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient - especially `HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use.`

Comment: Also you should use `PostAsync` instead of `SendAsync`, and await your requests to allow proper catching of exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

> If there is something i'm doing wrong ?

420 is the code you get from the server. It's not official, so you'd have to ask the server provider what it means and what you should do.

Normally, 420 is another way to say you are rate limited (so actually status code 429). You sent too many requests over a short timeframe, so the service is blocking you. Again, whether that is the case, what constitutes "too many" or "timeframe" in their implementation is specific to their implementation and is something we cannot say. Contact them and ask.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are being limited.

> The status code 420  : Not part of the HTTP standard, but introduced by Twitter. This was used by Version 1 of their API when requests from a particular client were being rate limited.

Answer (score 0):

The `420 Enhance Your Calm` status code means that you are being rate limited. It's similar to `429: Too many Requests`.
This means you are sending what they consider to be too many requests, too quickly.